# Designing a circuit to replace AA batteries with a LiPo battery

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, diodes

I’ve been looking at ways to replace 2 AA batteries in an older device I have with a LiPo battery and USB C charge board so that I can easily charge it up and save on batteries. The biggest barrier to doing so is that most LiPo batteries have an average output of 3.7 V rather than the 3v needed by the circuit, and start out at about 4.2 V which is far too high.

Some [videos](https://youtu.be/HzC0ZkB1fo8) I’ve seen solve this by placing a 1N4001 diode in series with the battery which drops the voltage down to ~3 V. I guess that might mean that it starts out a bit hot for the device, but overall that sounds fine to my electronically uneducated ear. I’ve noticed, however, that [companies](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wu5KwbUBlViVDhrnY3PNamuuw0cXOmg/view) who offer boards to do this same thing use voltage regulators (+ capacitors) and extra diodes. My question is why? I’m worried that there is something that I’m missing that could put the battery/device at risk.

Since the device already ran on AA batteries I would assume it doesn’t need a more stable voltage than the LiPo already provides (e.g. there is no reason I can see to cut the power below a certain voltage threshold). It could potentially have something to do with the low battery indicator that is triggered at 2.4 V, but I would have thought that that would work with the 1 diode circuit anyway. Or alternatively it could have something to do with not depleting the LiPo battery too much, but since the device cuts out at about 2.2 V, that’s unlikely to be an issue either.

Comment: It just depends on what you are powering. If you have a 3 V incandescent lamp (like might exist in older flashlights) and you use a diode to drop the voltage, and you don't mind the lamp life being somewhat affected then the diode is probably okay. If you were powering some life-saving device (such as a two-AA defibrillator -- should one exist), then you may not want to play around so much. What kinds of things are you considering? Anything critical or where you'd care if it was damaged and had to be replaced?

Comment: It’s just an old gameboy so nothing too critical. I guess I’m just wondering why the diode by itself will be less reliable/introduce more wear than the voltage regulator etc.? Or do you just mean that the battery won’t last as long? If the latter I guess that’s ok. (I’m very new to this so please excuse the simple questions!).

Comment: I don't use LiPo's much, just yet. But in general, I think they are fully charged at 4.2 V and then decline to some point (often 3.7 V or 3.6 V) where they are supposed to be recharged. The diode drops a variable voltage depending on the current drawn through it (increases by 100 mV or so for every 10X change in current.) With a light load (not a gameboy), the diode might drop only 500 mV. So 3.7 V to the load? With a heavier load (like a gameboy) it might drop 800 mV, and with a low-% LiPo that might mean 2.9 V. It's not perfect, is all. Some loads tolerate over-voltage inputs; some don't.

Comment: Is this a GBA, GBC, or GBP? It matters.

Comment: It’s a GBA, but it has a new backlit IPS screen so the current draw will be higher. Probably 120ma-150ma from what I’ve seen: https://gbatemp.net/threads/current-draw-tests-on-moded-gba-ags-101-original-cartridge-ez-flash-iv.496078/ (not the same screen as mine, but backlit). So is the idea that the voltage might be a bit high at the start which could introduce extra wear? Where as the voltage regulator will stop that initial spike?

Comment: The GBA (most of it, anyway) uses an internal 3.3 V supply rail. It will actually ***boost*** the AA voltages between the range of about 2.0 V up to 3.2 V to make that 3.3 V a stable voltage. You ABSOLUTELY cannot supply it with MORE than 3.2 V!!! It's not a buck-boost, inside. So it will just shut itself down (they designed it well) if you supply more. This is why I said that the load matters a lot.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. That actually reassures me if it is protected inside. This video shows it working so I’m guessing that the figures I’ve given you are wrong in some way: https://youtu.be/HzC0ZkB1fo8 . But as long as I’m not going to damage it I guess it’s ok to do without the voltage reg etc.?

Comment: No. I would want to MAKE SURE that the voltage is always below 3.2 V. That would scare me with a fresh LiPo, which is almost certainly higher.

Comment: Ah ok, I did wonder if the circuit in the video was a bit risky. It looks like I’ll have to learn a bit more about circuits and voltage regulators I guess. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah. The GBA wants 3.2 V ***or less***. Not more. So whatever you do, make sure that you get the voltage below. This is often called a "buck regulator" if it is efficient. A "linear regulator" will waste more energy.

Comment: They sold NiCd or NiMH battery packs for those... I had one in the day, that had a port for 5v DC adapter... Maybe use that instead of lipo?

Comment: I did think of that, but it seems they are all gone as far I can see.

Comment: @advert2013 Best thing would be to design a buck converter. Or buy something along these lines: [ebay module](https://ebay.us/FesC4C).

Comment: Yeah I think that sounds like the way to go, I have a few more questions about those, but I’ll do a new question rather than continue it here. Thanks again!